# pandas groupby with condition depending on same column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with `ID`, `date` and `number` columns and would like to create a new column that takes the mean of all numbers for this specific `ID` BUT only includes the numbers in the mean where date is smaller than the date of this row. How would I do this?

```
df = (pd.DataFrame({'ID':['1','1','1','1','2','2'],'number':['1','4','1','4','2','5'],
               'date':['2021-10-19','2021-10-16','2021-10-16','2021-10-15','2021-10-19','2021-10-10']})
      .assign(date = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x.date))
      .assign(mean_no_from_previous_dts = lambda x: x[x.date<??].groupby('ID').number.transform('mean'))
     )
```

this is what i would like to get as output

```
    ID  number  date    mean_no_from_previous_dts
0   1   1   2021-10-19  3.0 = mean(4+1+4)
1   1   4   2021-10-16  2.5 = mean(4+1)
2   1   1   2021-10-16  4.0 = mean(1)
3   1   4   2021-10-15  0.0 = 0 (as it's the first entry for this date and ID - this number doesnt matter, can e something else)
4   2   2   2021-10-19  5.0 = mean(5)
5   2   5   2021-10-10  0.0 = 0 (as it's the first entry for this date and ID)
```

so for example the first entry of the column `mean_no_from_previous_dts` is the mean of `(4+1+4)`: the first `4` comes from the column `number` and the 2nd row because 2021-10-16 (date in the 2nd row) is smaller than 2021-10-19 (date in the 1st row). The `1` comes from the 3rd row because 2021-10-16 is smaller than 2021-10-19. The second `4` comes from the 4th row because 2021-10-15 is smaller than 2021-10-19. This is for `ID = 1` the the same for `ID = 2`

Comment: `where date is smaller than the current date.` so it means all values is included, because today is `2021-10-20` ?

Comment: no, I mean the date of the current row. So for the first row: 2021-10-16, 2021-10-16 and 2021-10-15 are smaller than 2021-10-19, so take the mean: (4+1+4)/3

Comment: Hey i don't understand - what is the column of no_of_previous_dts?

Comment: I tried to edit it and make it clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is solution with numpy broadcasting per groups:

```
df = (pd.DataFrame({'ID':['1','1','1','1','2','2'],'number':['1','4','1','4','2','5'],
               'date':['2021-10-19','2021-10-16','2021-10-16','2021-10-15','2021-10-19','2021-10-10']})
      .assign(date = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x.date), number = lambda x: x['number'].astype(int))
      )
```

---

```
def f(x):
    arr = x['date'].to_numpy()
    m = arr <= arr[:, None]
    #remove rows with same values - set mask to False
    np.fill_diagonal(m, False)
    #set greater values to `NaN` and get mean without NaNs
    m = np.nanmean(np.where(m, x['number'].to_numpy(), np.nan).astype(float), axis=1)
    #assign to new column
    x['no_of_previous_dts'] = m
    return x

#last value is set to 0 per groups
df =  df.groupby('ID').apply(f).fillna({'no_of_previous_dts':0})
     
print (df)
  ID  number       date  no_of_previous_dts
0  1       1 2021-10-19                 3.0
1  1       4 2021-10-16                 2.5
2  1       1 2021-10-16                 4.0
3  1       4 2021-10-15                 0.0
4  2       2 2021-10-19                 5.0
5  2       5 2021-10-10                 0.0
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Its extremely slow with a bigger dataframe. Is there no pandas method to do this? Maybe something with rolling or rank?

Comment: @corianne1234 - If use `df['g'] = df.groupby(['ID','date']).cumcount()` and then `df1 = df.pivot('ID', ['date', 'g'], 'number').sort_index(axis=1)` what is `print (df1.shape)` ?